# Combining Multiple Models into one view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show data from 4 models into a single view. I have created a separate controller for this named posts_controller.rb and in views I have created posts folder and created index.html.erb file.

After that in controllers file I have added the following code.

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @quotes = Quote.all.order("created_at DESC")
        @images = Image.all.order("created_at DESC")
        @jokes = Joke.all.order("created_at DESC")

        @items = (@quotes.to_a + @jokes.to_a)
    end
end
```

And here is the view file where I am trying to show 2 items data as for now. But its not working. Pls check the code.

```
<% if @items.any? %>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <% @items.each.do |item| %>
      <% if item.is_a? Quote %>

      <div class="postbg">

              <%= quote.quotefie %>
              <div class="wedate pull-right wehi">
              <%= quote.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <em class="pull-right wehi" style="margin-top:20px;"> - <%= quote.author %></em>
              <%= link_to 'Show', quote %>
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_quote_path(quote) %>
              <%= link_to 'Destroy', quote, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
         </div>
    <% else %>

       <% @jokes.each do |joke| %>

       <div class="postbg">

              <%= joke.jokefie %>
              <div class="wedate pull-right wehi">
              <%= joke.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <%= link_to 'Show', joke %>
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_joke_path(joke) %>
              <%= link_to 'Destroy', joke, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
         </div>

         <% end %>
         <% end %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is the error it is showing.

```
undefined method `do' for #<Enumerator:0x007fd55fb032b8>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The above code is not working. I am unable to show 4 models data in one view.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Hi, yes it is showing undefined method `do' for #<Enumerator:0x007fd55fb032b8>

Comment: What is the error? post it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line here:

```
<% @items.each.do |item| %>
```

`do` defines a block, not a method call, so it should be:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
```

Note the removed `.`.

You've used `do` correctly further down the view when you use `@jokes.each do |joke|`.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
<% @items.each.do |item| %>
```

should be

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
```

Comment: @sevenseacat Now getting this error unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: @Sumeet You need to add `<% end %>` for the `do` just before the `<% else %>`